# Error in Folder Creation

Tags: android

I am using the below code to create a folder in pictures folder and toasting the path. 
but folder is not created i have mentioned write to external storage in android manifest.

```
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"College");
    if(!file.exists())
    {
        if(file.mkdir())
        {

            String f =file.getAbsolutePath();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),f,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Not Created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
```

please help me with the problem

Comment: Please check permission in your menifest  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: I have already added the permission

Comment: use `file.mkdirs()` instead of `file.mkdir()`

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me:

```
import java.io.File;

File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/College");

    try
    {
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Folder created at " + file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and  it worked

```
    File file;
    String CAMERA_DIR = "/dcim/";

    // Check that the SDCard is mounted
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {

        // Get the absolute path 
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "College");
        }
        else {
            file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + CAMERA_DIR + "College");
        }


        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! file.exists()) {
             if (! file.mkdirs()) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Not Created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 return;
             }
        }

         String f =file.getAbsolutePath();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),f,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        throw new IOException();
    }

}
```